Use all eight of the given polygons to tile a parallelogram
The goal of this puzzle is to use all eight of the given polygons to tile a parallelogram without gaps or overlaps.  Rotations and reflections are allowed.
Description of the polygons:
The triangles are equilateral with side length as indicated.
The quadrilaterals each have four equal side lengths as indicated and all their angles are either 60 or 120 degrees.


Attribution:  W. T. Tutte

Maybe add a no-computers tag? My computer very easily solves this, finding its unique solution, but I think this would be perfectly suited for solving by hand.

@JaapScherphuis I added your suggested tag.

@JaapScherphuis just out of curiousity, how did you program your computer to find the solution?

@Stevo I put it into my Polyform Solver program.

The answer is:

 

... the reason?

 


 I'm just considering a special case that satisfies the following conditions:
 1. The sum of the sides of two different polygons is the length of the third polygon. (e.g. 2+3=5, 2+7=9, ... like the purple arrows show in the diagram).
 2. If the sum of the sides of two different polygons is NOT the length of some 'third polygon', then I don't draw the arrows connected with it. (e.g. 2+8=10, 2+11=13, ...)
 3. Consider both incoming and outgoing arrows. A triangle has three sides, so there are three different edges connected with it; A parallelogram has four sides, so there are four different edges connected with it.
 4. and... $2^2 + 5^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 + 11^2 + \displaystyle\frac{3^2 + 9^2 + 12^2}{2} = 380= 19\times 20$


I believe that you should elaborate more on your reasoning, and not just provide a diagram.

A really interesting approach! Welcome to Puzzling!

+1 What a cool answer!  And welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

The total area of all tiles together is

 380 unit parallelograms. 19x20 is the only split able to accommodate the 11x11.

With that in mind it doesn't take much time to find:

 


Out of curiosity, did you work it out with arithmetic and sketches, or did you also make some paper/cardboard tiles to shuffle around?

@WeatherVane Just pencil and paper. Starting from the outside where edge lengths must sum to 19 or 20.

"doesn't take much time to find" LOL that would take me years to find!

@DmitryKamenetsky There are not many ways to place the largest two pieces without overlap, and the rest follows fairly quickly from there.
